# Are there any examples that gave a person new mental abililities after a head injury?

Tags: brain, injury

Are there any examples that gave a person new mental abilities  after a head injury or accident that he did not have earlier? Abilities like [Mental Abilities](http://www.livescience.com/45349-brain-injury-turns-man-into-math-genius.html)

Comment: What kind of mental abilities?

Comment: something like this [link](http://www.livescience.com/45349-brain-injury-turns-man-into-math-genius.html)

Comment: Jason Padgett's story is pretty intriguing, guess some day a movie could be easily made out of it.

Comment: @Vasudev gowda nice link

Comment: @Prince you are right. A nice movie would be made out of these rare mental phenomenon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An accident left Derek Amato with a severe concussion and a surprising ability to play the piano. One theory is that his brain reorganized, making accessible existing memories of music. Another is that his brain no longer filters sensory input, enabling him to hear individual notes rather than melodies.

http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-02/when-brain-damage-unlocks-genius-within

2.Shortly after her accident, the US-based woman, who has chosen to remain anonymous, began to develop extraordinary precise memories
•She is now able to recall exact details about every single place she has ever seen - and can draw a map or diagram of each location and building

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-3040907/Woman-reveals-ski-accident-left-phenomenally-advanced-mental-abilities-head-injury-developed-rare-brain-condition-known-acquired-savant-syndrome.html